# what is the benefit in dynamically generating java bean classes from xml?

Tags: java, jaxb

I had written a lot of java bean classes using my IDE. Another person suggests a different approach. He suggests that I put an xml file with bean definitions in them. Then I either use jaxb or xslt to dynamically generate the classes during build time. Though its a novel and interesting approach, I do not see any major benefit in it.

I see only one benefit in this suggested approach : The java bean classes need not be maintained in configuration control. Any bean changes is going to require only an update in the xml file.

Are there any major benefits in dynamically generating java classes ? Is there any other reason why this approach is taken ?

Comment: I'd like to see the source code for JAXB be written completely in XML. So to compile JAXB you'd have to run it through JAXB to generate the Java code...

Comment: I recently started a new project http://code.google.com/p/bdl/ which will reach a stable release the next weeks. It allows the generation of Java-Beans including custom code, attribute constraints, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Jibx and its generator in my project. My experience has been mixed.

1. The usual case for using JAXB's (XJC) generator is referred to in http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html
   Conversion to and from XML maked it possible to store in the DB and retrieve for future use as well as use for test case input for functional tests.
2. Using any kind of generator (Jaxb,Jibx,XMLBeans,Custom) might make sense for large sized projects. It allows for standardization of data  types (like BigDecimal for financial amounts, like ArrayList for all lists), forcing interfaces (like Serializable or Cloneable). This enforces good practices and reduce the need for reviews of generated files.
3. It allows for injection of code through XSLT or post processing of generated java file. Example is to inject Rounding code to a specific decimal size(2,6,9) with a specific policy (UP,DOWN,NEAR) within the setter method for each field of type financialAmount. Forcing such behavior does reduce the instance of bugs(for incorrect financial values which companies are liable for).

The disadvantage are

1. Usually each java class can be only a bean class. Any customization made will be overwritten. Since (in my case) the generator is tied in to the build process. The classes get generated with every build.
2. You cannot do implementation of your custom interfaces on a bean class or add annotations for your own or third party frameworks.
3. You cannot easily implement patterns like a factory method since default constructors are usually generated. Refactoring is usually difficult since generators do not usually support it.
4. You may(not sure now, was true a couple of years ago for Jibx) not be able to generated ENUMS when it would be most applicable.
5. You may not be able to override the default datatype with your own regardless of the need. CopyOnWrite list and not ArrayList for a variable shared across threads or a custom implementation of a List which also implements the Observer pattern.

The benefits of a generator outweigh the costs for large sized (in persons and not code, think 150 developers in three locations) distributed projects. You can work around the disadvantages by defining your custom classes which contain the bean and implements behaviour or post processing (adding additional code) with further metadata picked up from XSD annotations or another configuration file. Remember support and Maintenance of the generator become critical since the entire project depends on it. Use it with CAUTION.

For smaller sized projects I personally would write my own classes. For larger sized projects I personally would not use it in the middle tier mostly because of the lack of refactoring support. It can be used for simple beans meant to be bound to UI frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Akhilss. My experiences have been in large scale Java EE projects where code generation is common.

It all depends on your project. If you are coding only a few beans and only need basic functionality then I don't see the need to start with XML (Which is often over used anyway). Especially if you actually don't need the XML as well.

However if you are building a system which needs the XML, an example being a SOAP web service WSDL and schema, then generation is a good idea because it saves you from manually keep schemas and beans in sync. As well as providing factory classes and other support code.

As a counter argument, with EJB3 and similar standards, it's now often easier to write the beans and generate the messy XML stuff on the fly. Ie. let the server do the grunt work.

Another reason to consider code generation is if you require more complex functionality in your beans because they represent data structures. A few years ago I trialled the Apache Tuscany project for generating SDO beans from XML. The nice thing about that was that I could generate functionality like property change notifications so when I modified any of the bean's properties (including collections), other parts of your program could be notified automatically. Generated functionality like that can save you a lot of time and money if you need it.

Ultimately, I'd suggest adhering to the KISS principle. So don't add what you don't need. Generated code from XML is useful if it helps you in the long run. But like any technology, be sure you are adding it for the right reasons.